# angular2- how to share components between peer modules from one root module

Tags: angular

I have three module

1) common module

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    spinnerLoader
],
exports: [spinnerLoader]
})
export class commonModule { }
```

2) I have imported that to my root module

```
@NgModule({
import:[commonModule,thirdModule]

})
export class rootModule { }
```

3) I have a peer module as third module

```
@NgModule({

})
export class thirdModule { }
```

both common module and third module has been imported in root module, now common module has a component spinnerloader ,but when i use the spinner loader component to third module it doesn't work saying angular is not aware of spinner loader, but when i import the common module to third module it works, but this is now what i want, i want every common stuff to be in root module and every peer modules should use it, how can i attain the same.

please help me with the issue

Answer (score 0):

`thirdModule` also needs to import `commonModule`

```
@NgModule({
  import:[commonModule]
})
export class thirdModule { }
```

Each module must import modules where it used declarations from itself.
Imports to `rootModule` are only available to components that are in `declarations: [...]` of `rootModule`.

Comment: thanks for answer buddy but that is what my problem is i want doesn't want to import in each every peer modules, is there any way to attain this, because i think the above scenario was feasible in angular1

Comment: and the same scenario in facing in pipes also

Comment: Components in a module can only use what the module imports, not what any other module that imports this module imports. There are no global directives in Angular2. What you can do is to make a module that exports other modules, so that you can import everything by adding only a single module to `imports: [...]`

Comment: how to export modules  ??

Comment: Add it to exports like the `spinnerLoader` component. `exports: []` can export declarations and modules. Actually I don't know if you need to import a module in order to be able to export it (I don't use TS myself and Dart doesn't have modules), but I know this works, many of the modules shipped with Angular do exactly that.